# Modify django Admin forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have the following model form which I inherit in the majority of my models.

```
class UserStamp(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True,
                                   related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True,
                                   related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_updated_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Where I construct my own forms I use

```
form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
```

and everything is ok.

But not in admin (expecting staff users) because he uses his own forms.
What is the simplest way to make the admin forms work properly(something tha I don't need to do each of them from zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `save_model` in your ModelAdmin class.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.save()
```